# Ternary operator in HTML tag - Laravel 5.6 Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the below HTML tag where the value of "style" for nav tag should be loaded using ternary operator. I don't have any error but the desired result is not achieved

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel" 
style="{{ Request::path() }} == 'home' ? 'background-color: darkgrey' : '' ">
```

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong

Comment: You need to put your ternary inside the braces. Anything inside the braces is treated as PHP, anything outside, unless prepended with @, is treated as HTML.

Comment: Ahh.. Silly mistake.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel" 
style="{{ Request::path() == 'home' ? 'background-color: darkgrey' : '' }}">
```

Comment: thanks.. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with following.

```
{{ (Request::path() == 'home') ? 'background-color: darkgrey' : ''}}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple solution:

```
style="{{ Request::path() == 'home' ? 'background-color: darkgrey' : '' }}"
```